# Is it acceptable to omit 'of' in this sentence?

Tags: difference, usage

I think it is informal. Do you agree?

> Nothing of this size can be curbed, he argues.

vs.

> Nothing this size can be curbed, he argues.

Comment: Have you done any research? For example, have you done any searches for "nothing of this size" and "nothing this size" to see whether and how they are used?

Answer (score 2):

Technically it isn't strictly incorrect to exclude "of" in that sentence, but I would suggest that it would sound/appear wrong to most native speakers. As such, I would tend towards including it.